# how to find the ip address of a printer with its printer driver in java?

Tags: java, zebra-printers, printers

```
   PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);

    System.out.println("Available Printer Drivers:");
    for (PrintService service : printServices) {
        String printerName = service.getName();
        String driverClassName = (String) service.getAttribute(PrintServiceLookup.DRIVER);

        System.out.println("Printer Name: " + printerName);
        System.out.println("Driver Class Name: " + driverClassName);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

the above code will take the installed printer drivers and print that in console.

with that printer name i want to find the ip address assume every printer is connected to the wifi as the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not clear on what `PrintServiceLookup.DRIVER` is.  I see no DRIVER field in [the PrintServiceLookup class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/print/PrintServiceLookup.html).

You might be able to obtain the address from the PrintService’s [PrinterURI](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/print/attribute/standard/PrinterURI.html) attribute.  (I have no printers here, so I don’t currently have a way to verify whether this works.)

```
Optional<InetAddress> ipAddress = Optional.empty();

PrinterURI uriAttr = service.getAttribute(PrinterURI.class);
if (uriAttr != null) {
    URI printerURI = uriAttr.getURI();
    String hostname = printerURI.getHost();
    if (hostname != null) {
        ipAddress = Optional.of(InetAddress.getByName(hostname));
    }
}
```